# c# copy html links from webbrowser and write it in textfile

Tags: c#, .net, hyperlink, browser, web-scraping

i want to incorporate function of copying particular links from webbrowser and write it in textfile when the user clicks the button. please help me, this is the function I wrote :

```
public void grabLink()
        {
            HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser3.Document.Links ;

            foreach (HtmlElement  link in links)
            {
                if (link.InnerHtml.Contains("register"))
                {
                    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("link.tnx"))
                    {
                        tw.WriteLine(link.InnerHtml);
                    }
                }

            }
}

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grabLink();
        }
```

The link I want to copy is like

```
<a target="_blank" title="Accept" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fregister.mig33.co…gmail.com&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE1sLh2qmw-nEfj3exP8au_3dw3Kg">

    Sign Up Now For Free.

</a>
```

suggestions and advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe what's not working in your current function?

Comment: hi @will anderson , when the button is clicked and grablink() function is exceuted the textfile which is created shows "System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement" instead of links. I simply want the to copy the link in the webbrowser and save it in textfile

Comment: the html links that i want to copy from webbrowser are link <a target ="_blank" href="https://eragenx.com/referral/hhghgjhh89765"></a>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Try `tw.WriteLine(link.InnerHtml);`

Comment: i updated the codes but its not working :(

Comment: What is it outputting to the text file? "It's not working" makes it really hard to help debug

Comment: I tried outerhtml and outertext it simply outputs  >> sign up for free << whereas i want to get the encoded link that i will further decode.. i have edited the link that i want to copy

Comment: I just tested on my machine. You'll want link.OuterHtml if you want to copy the entire link. Also, you're checking that the InnerHtml contains "register", but your example link doesn't actually contain "register". Try changing your `Contains` call to something like "Sign Up"

Comment: after i changed the contains to "sign up" and the desired output to link.outerhtml the unexpected output that i am getting is it just displays text > "google home" < dnt know what i am missing or where i am going wrong.

Comment: hiyat got it, now i am getting entire link, but still one problem is thr, in the webpage thr are atleast 50 similar link with same attributes, but text writer displays only one, may be process.start will do?

Comment: Can you upload the contents of the page you're parsing, and the output you're getting? I think there must be some detail I'm missing. Also just noticed, you should move the TextWriter `using` outside the loop, otherwise you'll overwrite the file for every link.

Comment: yeaa thank you got it, i am  trying. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting our comment discussion as an answer in case it's useful to anyone else.

You need to use link.OuterHtml to capture the entire output. You're also matching the wrong string (per your link example).

You're also creating a new StreamWriter each time through the loop. This will cause you to only output the last link on the page. Try this:

```
public void grabLink()
{
    HtmlElementCollection links = webBrowser3.Document.Links ;

    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("link.tnx"))
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement  link in links)
        {
            if (link.InnerHtml.Contains("Sign Up"))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(link.OuterHtml);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got it, everything is working perfectly alright now. thanks a lot. :)